# g-e in augmentation ideal of subgroup H iff g in H

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $J_H$ the augmentation ideal of $H$. Then for $g\in G$ we have $g-e \in J_H$ iff $g\in H.$

In Daniel E. Cohen's *Groups of Cohomological Dimension One*, which can be found here: http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540057598 (Specifically Lemma 4.1 which is available for preview.)

This fact is proven, but I do not understand this proof (of part (i)). Is there someone who can explain this, or give more references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see the preview of the proof, but the result seems pretty straightforward. It is a known fact that the additive group of the augmentation ideal is (freely) generated by elements of the form {g-e}, for g non trivial elements of G(I don't know how to tex here, so please bear with me).

So, if g is an element of H, then g-e lies inside J_H.

For the reverse, if g-e lies inside J_H, then g-e is a Z-combination of elements of H and thus, it lies inside H.
Hope I helped (and not got too sloppy XD).

Comment: For $g-e$ to be a $\mathbb{Z}$-combination, don't we need $G$ to be abelian?

Comment: No, we don't. By "Z-combination", I mean that g-e is a formal sum of {n_h *h}, for h in H and n_h integers. The additive group of the augmentation ideal of course is commutative, since the augmentation ideal is the kernel of the map Z[G]-->Z. But commutativity of G doesn't play any role here.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I believe I understand the proof now. (:

Comment: No prob, man :)